# RcppArmadillo on several cpu cores

Tags: r, rcpp

I have the following RccpArmadillo function that runs fine if I execute it on one cpu core. But if I use several cores, then R will crash. All the other Rcpp functions I created so far run fine on several cores (with foreach), only RccpArmadillo seems to be problematic. Any ideas how to fix that?

```
cppFunction('double augmentedDickeyFullerCpp(NumericVector a, NumericVector b, double gamma, double mu, int lags) {

    if (gamma < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int n = a.size()-1;
    int lags2 = lags + 1;
    // first rows, then columns
    NumericMatrix x(n-lags2,lags2);
    NumericMatrix zdifflag(n-lags2+1,lags2);
    NumericVector diff(n);
    NumericVector zdiff(n-lags2+1);
    NumericVector residuals(n+1);
    residuals[0] = a[0] - gamma * b[0] - mu;


    // residuals a is y and b is x
    for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        residuals[i] = a[i] - gamma * b[i] - mu;
        diff[i-1] = residuals[i] - residuals[i-1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-lags2+1; i++) {
        zdifflag[0,i] = residuals[i+lags2-1];
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < n-lags2+1; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < lags2; i++) {
            x(j,i) = diff[j+lags2-1-i];
            if (i > 0) {
                zdifflag(j,i) = x(j,i);
            }
        }
        zdiff[j] = x(j,0);
    }

    int length = zdifflag.nrow(), k = zdifflag.ncol();

    arma::mat X(zdifflag.begin(), length, k, false); // reuses memory and avoids extra copy
    arma::colvec y(zdiff.begin(), zdiff.size(), false);
    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);    // fit model y ~ X
    arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;           // residuals

    // std.errors of coefficients
    //arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef[0]; 
    // sqrt(sum(residuals^2)/(length - k))
    double s2 = std::inner_product(res.begin(), res.end(), res.begin(), 0.0)/(length - k);                                                        
    arma::colvec std_err = arma::sqrt(s2 * arma::diagvec(arma::pinv(arma::trans(X)*X)));  

    return coef[0]/std_err[0];      

}',depends = "RcppArmadillo", includes="#include <RcppArmadillo.h>")
```

Answer (score 2):

I generally recommend putting the code into a small package, and having each parallel worker load the package.  That is known to work, both in serial and parallel, whereas relying on `cppFunction()` for an ad-hoc function may be too fragile for parallel execution.